# In Fallout New Vegas, how do I use Mojave Express Drop Boxes?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've been playing Fallout New Vegas and I spotted the Mojave Express drop box in Goodsprings, but I haven't seen any others.  Supposedly you can use these drop boxes to move items from place to place in the Wasteland, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

**How do you use Mojave Express Drop Boxes?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you've found another dropbox, you can send items from any of them to any other and then pick them up at the destination.

For locations (spoilers), see the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mojave_Express_dropbox).